# What does it mean to have 2 provisioning profile with same name and App Identifier but different profile identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning

I'm not sure how or why but now I have 2 provisioning profile for my phone that has the same name, same 'App Identifier' XXX.com.xxx.xxx.xxx but different 'Profile Identifier'

The two profiles are not exactly the same.

The two noticable difference are
1. Expiration date
2. Devices listed

My question is, is it safe to delete one or the other? This is an app that is used internally amongst 12 devices so I am worried that if I delete one of the profile, one of the device will not work.

Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an app has been signed with a mobileprovision, nothing you do in the provisioning portal will affect installed versions of that app in the field.  So, don't worry about making existing installs suddenly stop working - you can't.

It is totally safe to delete one or both of the provisions if you need to.